# Prime factorization of numbers in $1+6N$ and $5+6N$?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, natural-numbers

In my thesis I need to prove a certain statement for the cases where p is in 1+6N or in 5+6N.

For example $5+6N$:
I checked the numbers until $200$ and it seems as if all numbers in this set are
- prime
- the product of two distinct numbers
- a power of a certain prime number

If I could show that this this is true for all numbers in $5+6N$, then I could finish my proof.
Do you have any ideas or are there some properties of numbers out of this set? Some properties about the prime factorization of $p$ in $5+6N$ and $1+5N$ would be helpful..

Comment: This is for your thesis???

Comment: Of course this is not the main aspect I want to prove. Actually I'm investigating a particular coloring of torus knots and want to check, whether for certain p (here p in 1+6N or 5+6N) there is a q in N such that the torus knot T(p,q) is colorable. I guess that knowing more about the mentioned sets might help to finish my proof.

Answer (score 1):

$$ 7 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 \equiv 1 \pmod 6 $$
$$  5 \cdot 11 \cdot 17 \equiv 5 \pmod 6 $$
for example

$$  1729 = 1 + 6 \cdot 288 $$
$$ 935 = 5 + 6 \cdot 155 $$

Comment: Ok, so it seems that I have to come up with a different approach of my proof. Do you know whether none-primes of 1+6N or 5+6N have certain properties that might be useful, maybe some pattern in their prime factorization?

Comment: Take any product of (not necessarily distinct) primes $ > 3$, say $n = p_1 \ldots p_k$.  If the number of $p_k$ congruent to $5$ mod $6$ is even, then $n \equiv 1$ mod $6$; otherwise $n \equiv 5 \mod 6$.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check if that helps.